# What's the significance when a Heroku database URL is called 'HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL'?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

What's the "significance" - if any - when a database URL is called HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL? I've seen other names in Heroku's documentation such as 'HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL', HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL_URL,...

Does it mean it's always your primary database, or first database to be provision? I would love to know.

```
$ heroku pg:info
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:               Standard 0
Status:             Available
Data Size:          491.9 MB
Tables:             22
PG Version:         9.3.5
....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between colors of PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166080/what-is-the-difference-between-colors-of-postgresql)

Comment: The possible duplicate does not answer my question.

Comment: But is that because the question is different? Or that the only answer there doesn't really explain how and why Heroku picks color names?

Comment: The latter. If I have two heroku apps, with each a db, will I have have 2 'WHITE' URLs? Or, what happens if I provision a second DB for my main app... I suspect WHITE is always the main db for the app, but need someone to confirm. Also, what's the implication for the WHITE url say in a failover scenario? I'm hoping the answer would shed some light on this.

Comment: I run a whole host of heroku apps - each with different 'colored' database URLs - rose, gold, black, crimson, teal, olive, red, maroon... the list goes one!  Some applications share colors, while others have different ones.  I'm not sure of the significance (if any).

Comment: "Some applications share colors"... does that mean these applications share the same database? Sounds like there's no significance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Colors are picked randomly and exist uniquely in the scope of the application the database was created on. Across multiple applications, colors have no meaning or correlation.

By example, you can have 2 applications with 4 distinct databases using only 3 colors:

- my_awesome_application

  - HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL
  - HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL
- my_other_thing

  - HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE_URL
  - HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL

The color in `db:info` marked `(DATABASE_URL)` is the one your application is connecting to (unless you've configured something else). If you look at `heroku config`, you'll see something like

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL=postgres://path.to:a/db
DATABASE_URL=<the same value WHITE has>
```

If you've provisioned other databases on the same app, like followers, you'll see more colors in `config` with different URLs. If they're followers, `pg:info` tells you which DB they're following.

Comment: Just for fun, I counted all the colors on my company's 34 Heroku applications, and all the colors that are DATABASE_URLs: https://gist.github.com/kristjan/e8222575114bd8fafe8e. There was an overabundance of WHITE, but it means nothing, and WHITE wasn't assigned to DATABASE_URL significantly more often than anything else.

Comment: Awesome Kristján! I like you breakdown of URL colors.