# Managing multiple PostgreSQL instances on Heroku (Django project)

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I’m taking John Elder’s Udemy course titled: “[How To Push Django Python Apps To Heroku for Web Hosting](https://www.udemy.com/course/push-django-python-apps-to-heroku/learn/lecture/11518542)”. I've pushed to Heroku successfully already. Now I am experimenting with other aspects of deploying my Django project, specifically managing PostgreSQL.

When I initially set everything up 2 weeks ago, it appears I created three PostgreSQL database instances. [See here for a screenshot on imgur](https://i.imgur.com/VGwQISk.jpg).

My question: In that screenshot of my Heroku dashboard, what are the second and third configuration entries for?

I’ve already got some non-critical data in production on my live demo site. I’d like to delete the two of the three duplicate PostreSQL instances that I am not using but I’m curious and would first like to establish which one is the active one and which two are not.

What is a potential use case for even having multiple duplicate databases? Rolling back a database to a given state (like by using PostreSQL’s [Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery (PITR)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/continuous-archiving.html) feature) and [importing/exporting instances](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) are ways of backing up and restoring data which have been corrupted. But how are those features different or similar from configuring more than one db URL in the Heroku dashboard, as depicted in my imgur screenshot above?

I’ve Googled around using search terms such as ‘config vars heroku django postgresql colors’ (and variations) which loop me around to Heroku’s [Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) doc without addressing multiple PostgreSQL instances, like in my situation. Turning to Heroku’s [Databases & Data Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/data-management) doc explains how to handle PostgreSQL but doesn’t refer to configuration variables.

Comment: Colors are picked randomly and exist uniquely in the scope of the application the database was created on,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858588/whats-the-significance-when-a-heroku-database-url-is-called-heroku-postgresql this link will help you, and you can use heroku commands to download, restore the database backup  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups

Comment: According to your first link there, it seems to me like duplicate db's (specified by different colors, which are listening on different ports) are redundancies which can serve various purposes. So does this mean that deleting one or two of them is 'safe' and I wouldn't lose any data in production?

Comment: Yes you are right, these are only the backups of your database. you would not lose any data on production while deleting those files